# Change Tabs title style like Play store

Tags: android, tabs, styles

Hi,

I want to change the tabs style because, when there are many tabs, they just get smaller and the title text splits. So I was wondering, if anyone knows about how to change the style, the Play Store?

this [image]  to -> [image: See image example] this

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: take a look at this useful [link](http://viewpagerindicator.com/).

Answer (score 2):

There is a Android Widget that does exactly that:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html

Usage example:

http://blog.pboos.ch/post/40575809334/android-pagertabstrip-viewpager

Downside: it will only show 3 Tabs - current, previous and next.

Answer (score 0):

You need ViewPageIndicator's Title indicator -> http://viewpagerindicator.com/

[image]